# Laravel 8 Validation "required" not consistent with documentation

Tags: axios, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I've been stuck checking all the related rules for an hour:

Here is my validation rule request:

```
class CreateRewardRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function rules()
    {
        return [
            'parameters.name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1'],
            'parameters.maxQty' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1'],
            'parameters.maxPerUser' => ['nullable', 'min:1'],
            'parameters.maxPerDay' => ['nullable', 'min:1'],
            'parameters.pickWeight' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is my test request:

```
parameters[name]: null
parameters[maxQty]: null
parameters[maxPerUser]: null
parameters[maxPerDay]: null
parameters[pickWeight]: null
```

The error response:

```
{
    "message":"The given data was invalid.",
    "errors":{
        "parameters.maxQty":["The parameters.max qty must be an integer."],
        "parameters.pickWeight":["The parameters.pick weight must be an integer."],
    }
}
```

The `parameters.name` field is not even mentioned in the error, but the doc says:

**[required](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required)**

```
The field under validation must be present in the input data and not empty. 
A field is considered "empty" if one of the following conditions are true:

The value is null.

The value is an empty string.
```

I want to reject NULL value for this field, because it is "required", but it doesn't seem to work.

If I don't send the field I do have the validation error showing up, but I don't want an empty/null value to pass validation.

Did I miss anything here?

Thanks!

PS: Here is the VueJS code in case my form submission might be the culprit:

```
  let formData = new FormData();
  for (let param in this.parameters) {
    if (this.parameters.hasOwnProperty(param)) {
      formData.append('parameters[' + param + ']', this.parameters[param]);
    }
  }
  axios.post("/api/JdCode", formData).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

**EDIT:** Using `dd($request->all())`, I noticed that all `null` FormData values are treated as `string "null"`, which is why `required` rule doesn't work on `name` field, and that `maxQty` and `pickWeight` `required` rule does not trigger any error, but `integer` fires a `must be an integer` error, since it receives a "null" string.
Not sure if I'm clear, but it looks like a bug related to requests sent with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add the 'present', 'not_in:null' or Rule::requiredIf(true),

```
public static function rules()
    {
        return [
            'parameters.name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'not_in:null'],
            'parameters.maxQty' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1', 'present'],
            'parameters.maxPerUser' => ['nullable', 'min:1'],
            'parameters.maxPerDay' => ['nullable', 'min:1'],
            'parameters.pickWeight' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1', 'present'],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Hello @ApCo, thanks for your help, it seems that `not_in:null` prevents `null` values to be accepted for a field having `required|string` rules, which is weird because the doc states that `required` does exactly that: "required => considered empty if value is null".
I noticed that this problem only applies for fields having `string` rule, since for `maxQty` having `required|integer` rules, `null` triggers a `field required` validation error.

Comment: Digging more, I notice that `'max_per_user' => ['nullable', 'min:1']` triggers a DB error if left null: `Incorrect integer value: 'null'`, when I leave it untouched.
If I `dd($request->all())` I can see that `null` is actually treated as string `"null"`, which seems to be the cause of this error.
But since the same thing happens to field `name` if I leave it empty, I wonder how the `not_in:null` rule rejects a `"null"` string...
I'm totally confused here, if I filter out the `null` fields out of the FormData everything works fine.
Should I file a bug related to FormData+Validation?